# How to set up a grid of buttons in bootstrap?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have about 20 buttons I want to show. (Radio stations for http://radio.meteor.com/.)

Here's what the Meteor/Handlebar HTML looks like now:

```
<div id="channels" class="span12">
  <div class="btn-group">
    {{#each channels}}
    <button class="btn {{#if playing}}btn-primary{{/if}}" id="channel-{{name}}">
      {{name}}
    </button>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</div>
```

I want buttons to go both in a vertical and a horizontal direction. I thought btn-group would be fine but my buttons go to the far left.  I tried this in vain:

```
#channels button {
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
}
```

Comment: I've noticed with your website that you set the element 'container' opacity to 0.9 making the whole div 0.9. If you just want the background color to be slightly transparent use rgba(0,0,0,0.9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each li is set as 100% the width of the ul parent, instead the css for channels li should be:

```
#channels li {
   float: left;
   width: auto;
}
```

Comment: do you mean button instead of li?